# connection reset - apns

Tags: apple-push-notifications, javapns, sslexception

I got an exception when send a push notification in PROD environment but it works in UAT environment.I'm getting below exception,

Exception while waiting for error code: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Why I got this exception and how to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are using different certificates for different environment. Apple provides different certificate on basis of environment eg. Production , sandbox. You get this option while creating certificate.